# The surfaces of a gaming dice are labeled with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. How many different gaming dice exist?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The surfaces of a gaming dice are labeled with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. How many different gaming dice exist, if each face of the dice is marked with a different number from 1 to 6, and no two faces can have the same number (consider rotations)?

Is this explanation correct? Let's just take the first symbol. It must be somewhere, and we just position the dice to have this symbol at the bottom. This already fixes the opposite side, and for that we now have 5 different possibilites, which symbol is on there. Now pick one of the four remaining symbols and rotate the dice so that it's on front. This now fixes the other 3 sides, so there are 3·2·1=6 possibilities to place the 3 symbols on there. So that's a total of only 30 different dice with 6 different symbols.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  When are two configurations the same?  I suggest:  explain how you got $24$...that might clarify the rules.

Comment: Should say:  given the placement of the $1$, there are $5$ choices for the opposite face, so it seems that the answer should be divisible by $5$.

Comment: I have added a more precise question and explanation.

Comment: That explanation is too terse.  My suggestion:  as before, note that there are $5$ choices for the face opposite the $1$.  Then, with that choice made, we have four unused values for the other faces.  Once you pick a pair from those, you are done.  (why?)

Comment: I have added a more precise question and explanation again.

Comment: Sure, that explanation is fine.